# Detect last row and add one

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5

In my application i display item's. My `JSON` feed contains 50 items but first i want to display 25 and when a user scrolls down to the last row it need to load more items.

i'm doing:

Downloading the `JSON` feed;

```
NSString *jsonString = [NSString 
                        stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:xmlDataUrl] 
                        encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy
                        error:nil];
SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
NSDictionary *results = [parser objectWithString:jsonString error:nil];
parser = nil;
[self setTableData:[results objectForKey:@"feed"]];
```

//

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}
```

//

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        //return [tableData count];
        return 25;
    }
```

And detect last row:

```
   if(indexPath.row == [self.tableData count] - 1) 
    {

        NSLog(@"Last Row");
    }
```

But it's not detecting the last row. Is this because the JSON it's downloading contains more than 25 rows?

And how i can add a new row is something like `[self.tableDate count] +1;` possible?

If i do return `[tableData count];` it's detecting the last row but the rows are already filled for 100% i need to display 25/50 and than +1

Comment: You won't be able to add rows because you hard code 25 as the number of rows in the section.

Comment: i could do ; `return [tableData count];` but then it will download display all the items, can i set a max and later +1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where are you calling that second block of code? Is it in your table delegate's willDisplayCell: method?

In one of my projects, I have very similar code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == self.search.count && [tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows containsObject:indexPath])
    {
        [self.search findMoreStuff];
    }
}
```

With an extra row appended after the ones created for self.search, so in my case I'm checking for self.search.count, but you probably want to look at self.search.count-1

Comment: What do u mean with second block of code? The 'Last Row' part? In forRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the    if(indexPath.row == [self.tableData count] - 1) 
line.  That has to be called in willDisplayCell: